# Unable to push code: Defining testmethods methods must be declared as @isTest

Tags: apex, managed-package, deprecation

new this week after SF patches in the inability to push code for our packages. We are trying to get around this bug:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC

but after changing API to v28.0

We are getting the error that we must use @isTest instead of testMethod.

```
@Deprecated global static testMethod void OperationsTest1() {
}
```

The problem

1. Method is global (legacy mistake)
2. Method is @Deprecated
3. Cannot remove since it was previously packaged
4. Cannot use both @Deprecated and @istest on the same method that I can tell.

API version of class is set to 28

Any ideas on how we can comply with the new rules for @isTest in this situation?

We are now stuck unable to push code due to dependencies on this main class and I do not see a way to comply at this point.

Comment: Why not just take out `testMethod` and empty the contents of the body? That should fix the problem, at least.

Comment: @sfdcfox thought about that but then the method would appear in the WSDL right for existing customers even if deprecated? Also not sure if that is considered a change in signature or not. I have not had time to fully vet the consequences yet

Comment: I haven't tried this, since I'm not in the "isv managed package" environment, but it seems that deprecated methods shouldn't appear in WSDL's for versions where the method is deprecated? I'd be interested in learning what you find out about this.